# How to iterate through all users belonging to another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project to allow a teacher to do batch grade creation for students. I already have standard grade creation working fine when doing it for a specific student.

A teacher (`User`) has a number of students (`User`) that belong to them. What I'm trying to achieve is when you click 'create batch of grades', it takes you to the `create_grade_path` for the first student where you can input the grade and click create. This takes you to the `create_grade_path` for the next student and so on until all students have had a grade created.

My question is in a general sense what would be the best way to iterate through them as I haven't come across something like this. I have a variable `@all_students` that is an array of all students belonging to the current logged in teacher. Would I create copy of this and remove records from it until it's empty?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

First consider adding additional parameter, something like `batch_update`, to your `create_grade_path` route. This parameter will indicate if this is batch or single create action.

If this is batch request, after successful save you need to redirect to grade view for another student. You can do that in many ways. You can fetch from database another student that doesn't have grade or you can use session for storing ids of students that need grades. With session you need to create another action that will initiate whole process.

```
def start_batch_create
  @all_students = Student.all # or other query
  sessions[:students_to_grade] = @all_students.map(&:id)
end
```

Now in create action you can access this session variable remove one student and redirect to create grade for another student unless there are some ids in the session variable.